# Iron router cannot open mongo console

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I am using iron router and unfortunately every time i cd into a directory generated by iron cli,i am notified i am not in a meteor directory.

So i have tried iron mongo and opens

```
> meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7

connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
```

but has been this way for the last five minutes. Is there an alternative way to access the mongodb that comes with meteor or what should be done incase you are using iron router?.

In my case,i just want to see how many collections i have like

```
show collections
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the local mongo connection string first then connect as follows

```
God@God-HP-EliteBook-2540p:~/crud$ iron mongo
> meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7

connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor

^C
God@God-HP-EliteBook-2540p:~/crud$ mongo mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
```

Feed commands

```
God@God-HP-EliteBook-2540p:~/crud$ mongo mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
meteor:PRIMARY> show collections
Cannot use 'commands' readMode, degrading to 'legacy' mode
crud
meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration
roles
system.indexes
users
meteor:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin   (empty)
local   0.063GB
meteor  0.031GB
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is best way for you it is use some Admin UI. Check "mongodb admin ui" in google for variants.

**For my part I can recommend:**

### [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/)

Its is really perfect mongo manager. Native and cross-platform MongoDB manager
Whatever platform you use today — Robomongo is available for you. Distributed as a native application, fast and snappy Robomongo uses very little of your machine resources.
But if you find some critical for you bugs, try another perfect tool

### [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/downloads/)

MongoVUE is an innovative MongoDB desktop application for Windows OS that gives you an elegant and highly usable GUI interface to work with MongoDB. Now there is one less worry in managing your web-scale data.

Comment: if you run into problems: feel free for ask! :)